# Inequality between three sequences

Tags: inequality

let three positive integer sequences $\boldsymbol{h}=(h_1,h_2,...,h_{t_1})$ of length $t_1$, $\boldsymbol{m}=(m_1,m_2,...,m_{t_2})$ of length $t_2$, and $\boldsymbol{k}=(k_1,k_2,...,k_{t_3})$ of length $t_3$, where all the values of $t_1,t_2, \text{and} \ t_3 \geq1$. If We have the following three relations such that
$$(1). \space h_1<h_2<,...<h_{t_1}<m_1<m_2<,...,<m_{t_2}<k_1<k_2<,...,<k_{t_3} \space,$$
$$(2). \space t_1+t_3=t_2 \space,$$
$$(3). \space \sum_{1}^{t_1}h_{i}^{2}+\sum_{1}^{t_3}k_{i}^{2}=\sum_{1}^{t_2}m_{i}^{2}\space.$$
We need to proof that
$$\sum_{1}^{t_1}h_{i}^{4}+\sum_{1}^{t_3}k_{i}^{4}>\sum_{1}^{t_2}m_{i}^{4} \space.$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.